# How to stop url param manipulation

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following URL on a web application that I have created (currently running locally):
http://localhost:8080/trustsurvey/questionView.php?question=1

The question=1 is from a GET parameter that increments each time the user clicks on the Next button.

```
$questionNumber = $_GET['question'];
```

What would be the best recommended way to hide or encode the parameter in URL after the `?` thus making it difficult for a user to manipulate the URL and manually change the parameter?

Comment: There is no way of stopping this. You could use POST, it will stop things being in the URL, but they are still able to be manipulated by the user. The solution is proper validation and sanitisation of those values before you use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent user from manipulating query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660611/prevent-user-from-manipulating-query-string-parameter)

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of [session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) instead of URL parameters.

Something like this (not "complete" code, some `isset` checks are missing etc):

### questionView.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$questionNumber = $_SESSION['questionNumber'] = $_SESSION['questionNumber'] ?? 1;
?>

<form method="post" action="answer.php">
<!-- Display question $questionNumber here -->
</form>
```

### answer.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$questionNumber = $_SESSION['questionNumber'];

if (answerOk()) {  // This checks answer with $_POST data
  $_SESSION['questionNumber']++;
  header('Location: questionView.php');
  die;
}
```